# CWP https non-www redirect failed in both htaccess and apache

Tags: .htaccess, centos7, cwp

i tried to make my website working only within non-www https (ex, https://customsite.tld)

i want all request to my domain to be server from "https://customsite.com"

i have tried to many things but all of them doesnt work & websites insists to open using same www url "https://www.customsite.com"

things that i have tried are as follows :
- i make sure that apache "rewrite_module" is loaded

- changing AllowOverride to Allow within apache configurations (main & vhost config)
- redirect within Apache configuration

```
Redirect permanent / https://customsite.com/
```

- i used to many code within htacces the following is my current htaccess (but it doesnt work too)

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.customsite\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://customsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

- i also enabled rewrite log & when trying to accsee site using www it gives me the following

```
    [Mon Sep 30 11:59:52.772074 2019] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5473:tid 140059438470912] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 197.37.110.119:59413] 197.37.110.119 - - [www.customsite.com/sid#13141e8][rid#7f620c01fcd0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /login
    [Mon Sep 30 11:59:52.772105 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5473:tid 140059438470912] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 197.37.110.119:59413] 197.37.110.119 - - [www.customsite.com/sid#13141e8][rid#7f620c01fcd0/initial] pass through /login
    [Mon Sep 30 11:59:52.895060 2019] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5473:tid 140059430078208] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 197.37.110.119:59413] 197.37.110.119 - - [www.customsite.com/sid#13141e8][rid#7f620c01a100/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /css/main.css, referer: https://www.customsite.com/login
    [Mon Sep 30 11:59:52.895081 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5473:tid 140059430078208] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 197.37.110.119:59413] 197.37.110.119 - - [www.customsite.com/sid#13141e8][rid#7f620c01a100/initial] pass through /css/main.css, referer: https://www.customsite.com/login
    [Mon Sep 30 11:59:53.084281 2019] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5472:tid 140059472041728] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 197.37.110.119:59415] 197.37.110.119 - - [www.customsite.com/sid#13141e8][rid#7f620c01f870/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /css/auth.css, referer: https://www.customsite.com/login
    [Mon Sep 30 11:59:53.084336 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5472:tid 140059472041728] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 197.37.110.119:59415] 197.37.110.119 - - [www.customsite.com/sid#13141e8][rid#7f620c01f870/initial] pass through /css/auth.css, referer: https://www.customsite.com/login
    [Mon Sep 30 11:59:53.665350 2019] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5472:tid 140059455256320] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 197.37.110.119:59415] 197.37.110.119 - - [www.customsite.com/sid#13141e8][rid#7f620c01a100/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /images/e-learn2.png, referer: https://www.customsite.com/login
    [Mon Sep 30 11:59:53.665373 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5472:tid 140059455256320] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 197.37.110.119:59415] 197.37.110.119 - - [www.customsite.com/sid#13141e8][rid#7f620c01a100/initial] pass through /images/e-learn2.png, referer: https://www.customsite.com/login
    [Mon Sep 30 11:59:53.670419 2019] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5473:tid 140059353282304] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 197.37.110.119:59413] 197.37.110.119 - - [www.customsite.com/sid#13141e8][rid#7f620c01fcd0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /images/bg7.png, referer: https://www.customsite.com/css/auth.css
    [Mon Sep 30 11:59:53.670441 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5473:tid 140059353282304] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 197.37.110.119:59413] 197.37.110.119 - - [www.customsite.com/sid#13141e8][rid#7f620c01fcd0/initial] pass through /images/bg7.png, referer: https://www.customsite.com/css/auth.css
```

i have Centos 7 with Centos Web Panel installed, & the script is running on nodejs so i am proxying nodejs to port 80 using the following

```
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4000/
```

the problem is that the website no matter any htaccess code nor redirect within apache it is always opening "https://www.customsite.com"
i need it to be without www & only within https
why this doesnt work ? this is getting me very crazy !!
any help will be appreciated 
thanks in advance for eveyone,,

Comment: any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i used mod env to redirect instead of htaccess, 
thanks for all